# Display Carousel only if the image exists

Tags: reactjs, carousel

I imagine this is a reasonably easy question but as I am new to react I am having some difficulties. I would like to present in my Carousel only the images that exist, otherwise, I would not display anything on the screen.
Currently with my code, the images appear but when there is an image that does not exist, a new tab of the carousel is presented blank.
Is there a way to simply cancel Carousel if there is no image for it?

My code:

```
          <div>
            <Carousel>
                {images[0]?(<CarouselModel image={images[0]} />):null}
                {images[1]?(<CarouselModel image={images[1]} />):null}
                {images[2]?(<CarouselModel image={images[2]} />):null}
                {images[3]?(<CarouselModel image={images[3]} />):null}
                {images[4]?(<CarouselModel image={images[4]} />):null}
                {images[5]?(<CarouselModel image={images[5]} />):null}
                {images[6]?(<CarouselModel image={images[6]} />):null}

              
            
            </Carousel>
        </div>
```

Then, my Carousel displays like this:

[image: Carousel Tabs]

Getting the images - I know its kinda messy but I will improve it later on, just for testing.

```
const displayInteriorImages = () => {
    let images 
    let images2 
    let images3 
    let images4 
    let images5 
    let images6 

images=(
        <div  className='itemWrapper' >
            <div className='item'id="item">
                {
                    listing.photo_1 ? (
                        <div className='listingdetail__display'>
                            <img className='listingdetail__display__image' src={listing.photo_1} alt='' />
                        </div>
                    ) : null
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    images2=(
        <div  className='itemWrapper' >
            <div className='item'id="item">
                {
                    listing.photo_2 ? (
                        <div className='listingdetail__display'>
                            <img className='listingdetail__display__image' src={listing.photo_2} alt='' />
                        </div>
                    ) : null
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );

    images3=(
        <div  className='itemWrapper' >
            <div className='item'id="item">
                {
                    listing.photo_3 ? (
                        <div className='listingdetail__display'>
                            <img className='listingdetail__display__image' src={listing.photo_3} alt='' />
                        </div>
                    ) : null
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );

    images4=(
        <div  className='itemWrapper' >
            <div className='item'id="item">
                {
                    listing.photo_4 ? (
                        <div className='listingdetail__display'>
                            <img className='listingdetail__display__image' src={listing.photo_4} alt='' />
                        </div>
                    ) : null
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );

    images5=(
        <div  className='itemWrapper' >
            <div className='item'id="item">
                {
                    listing.photo_5 ? (
                        <div className='listingdetail__display'>
                            <img className='listingdetail__display__image' src={listing.photo_5} alt='' />
                        </div>
                    ) : null
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );

    images6=(
        <div  className='itemWrapper' >
            <div className='item'id="item">
                {
                    listing.photo_6 ? (
                        <div className='listingdetail__display'>
                            <img className='listingdetail__display__image' src={listing.photo_6} alt='' />
                        </div>
                    ) : null
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
       return [images, images2,images3,images4,images5,images6];
};


let images =displayInteriorImages()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map so that it only creates `CarouselModel` for items in Array. Make sure the array doesn't contain false values though.

```
<div>
     <Carousel>
        {
         images.map(img => (<CarouselModel image={img}/>))
        }
    </Carousel>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Good way to narrow the code too.

Answer (score 0):

you could filter the array first and then use map to return an array of components:

```
<Carousel>
  // if the image is null or undefined it will be rejected
  {images.filter(img => img).map(img => <CarouselModel image={img}>)}
</Carousel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it helped me a lot